# Передача динамических данных из view в шаблон

Tags: python, django

Только начал изучать джанго. Есть подключаемый шаблон base.html в котором лежит навбар. Вот так я передаю категории из views:

```
def base(request):
categories = Category.objects.all()
context = {
    'categories': categories
}
return render(request, "blog/base.html", context)
```

Вот так принимаю в base.html

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ category.translate }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Вроде бы шаблон все видит, т.е. все подсвечивается, но на странице index.html и др. никаких данных не отображается. Что я делаю не так, куда копать? Если в неподключаемый шаблон передаю данные, то все работает, получется проблема где-то здесь, но что-то я не могу найти решение.

Comment: Оказывается данные не прилетают, буду разбираться

Comment: А «на странице index.html и др.» во вьюхах, которыми рисуются эти страницы, вы `categories` в контекст пихаете? Если нет — то вот и ответ, надо пихать, джанга за вас ничего делать не будет

Comment: В контекст "пихаю", но данные не прилетают, если в urls.py не прописан  path(). Вопрос - можно без этого передавать данные из view в шаблон? Погуглил - везде работает без url-ов, а у меня шаблон видит, что приходит context, но данных в нем нет